# How to set image url as background of an ImageView using data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am already having a binding adapter to load the image in the ImageView coming from the URL. Now, I need to load background image URL as the background of the Image View and I am using data binding, glide to load images and writing it in Kotlin.

How can I write a binding adapter for the same?

Here is my XML

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView

        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:backgroundImageUrl="@{item.backgroundImageUrl}"
        app:mainImageUrl="@{item.mainImageUrl}"/>
```

Comment: Simple just make method for taking url and imageview as parameter and call that method.

Comment: Here [Binding image using bindAdapter](https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc) is the example for the same, instead of Picasso use glide for your work

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I already have a method to load image to image view. If i do the same for background image, no background image shows up

Comment: Check @PJain 's Answer.

Comment: Here is the binding adapter that I used to load the image coming from url to image view          @BindingAdapter("ImageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl:String?) {
    Glide.with(view.context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(view)
}

Comment: Now, I need to load background image url as background and when I used similar binding adapter, the background image won't load. I am not sure but I guess there is difference as image is android:src and background is android:background..can someone help me out?

Comment: what are you using in imageView?

Comment: You can make a trick to use another imageView as a background of your current imageView. And load image from URL as current image loading functionality. In this way another imageView will be created but its a simple solution.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: @humbleDev please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_background"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        app:mainImageUrl="@{item.backgroundImageUrl}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_main"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        app:mainImageUrl="@{item.mainImageUrl}"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For checking purpose I just set the alpha for the background image.

Hope this trick will help you.

[image]

Comment: I liked the idea but it still didn't work for me. Do you know how I can convert images that are loaded from glide into bitmap in the binding adapter? That will work I guess

Comment: Why you need to get the image bitmap?

Comment: The solution that you mentioned affects layout performance as we are creating a separate image view just to set background image. Most of the solutions that I saw were converting the glide loaded images into a bitmap object to set background. I am not getting how to write the code for it

Comment: Basically, the bitmap things work to download the image from URL by data streaming. And then set that bitmap to the image view. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following Binding Adapter and it's working fine.

```
@BindingAdapter("backgroundImageUrl")
 fun loadBackgroundImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl:String?)
{
Glide.with(view.context).load(imageUrl).into(object:SimpleTarget<Drawable>()
{
override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in 
Drawable>?) 
{
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
 view.background = resource}
 }
 })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

```
    try {
        ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you help me using glide and then converting it into bitmap?